# Reading User Input: How do I read, and print user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

Using this code code:

```
person = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello', person, '!')
```

Like this:

```
Enter your name: david
```

Gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    person = input('Enter your name: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'david' is not defined
```

Comment: You're obviously running Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3?

Comment: You are using Python 2. In Python 2 the function your are looking for is called `raw_input()`. It's the same as Python 3's `input()` function.

Comment: If running on a Debian-based distro, `python` is python 2, if you want python 3 you must type `python3` explicitly.